# Ranges in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, range

How do I write code to return a range of 10 numbers from a given number.

i.e if I am given **5**, code should `return 0..9`

**358** should `return 350..359`

**33** should `return 30..39  etc`

Comment: Already answered but here a nice brief article on ranges if you want to have a look: https://javing-uk.medium.com/ranges-arrays-basics-in-kotlin-2e2a5218c490

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the given number is integer type, you can simply write

```
val x = 358
(x / 10 * 10)..(x / 10 * 10 + 9)
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean something like this?

```
fun range10(contained: Int): IntRange {
    val start = contained - contained % 10
    val end = start + 9
    return start..end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```kotlin
fun answer(givenNum: Int) : IntRange {
    val startOfRange = givenNum - (givenNum % 10)
    return startOfRange until (startOfRange + 10)
}

fun main() {
    val givenNum = 33
    println(answer(givenNum)) // 30..39
}
```